# Multiple input fields to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've a form which has input fields as shown in figure below. Each time I click the add button, the row containing the input fields is appended.
[image]

The html code goes like this :

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="row ifields">
                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" placeholder="Product Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control text-center" name="pquantity" placeholder="Product Quantity" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <select class="form-control text-center" name="qtype">
                        <option value="g">g</option>
                        <option value="Kg">Kg</option>
                        <option value="ml">ml</option>
                        <option value="L">Lt.</option>
                        <option value="pc">Pc</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="pcost" placeholder="Product Cost" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"><button class="btn btn-default add-btn">Add</button></div>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row iclone"></div>
 </div>
```

And the Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add-btn').click(function(){
            var cl = $('.ifields').first('.row').clone(true);
            $('.iclone').append(cl);

        });
});
```

I want to go through each row and create a JSON file. For ex:

```
[{
  "product" : "A",
  "quantity" : "100",
  "quantitytype" : "g",
  "cost" : "100"
},
...
....
]
```

How to do create this JSON output ? Please guide.

Comment: Do you know how to select itens in jQuery? How to loop them? Just search this two things and you'll get your answer.

Comment: you create JSON "output" using `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create the required array of objects. Try this:

```
var data = $('.row.ifields').map(function() {
    return {
        product: $(this).find('[name="pname"]').val(),
        quantity: $(this).find('[name="pquantity"]').val(),
        quantityttype: $(this).find('[name="qtype"]').val(),
        cost: $(this).find('[name="pcost"]').val()
    };
}).get();
```

You can then use the `data` array as required - presumably in a `$.ajax()` call.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dgLoft4g/)